# How do I calculate the length of continuous occurrences of a value (uptimes) in a matrix?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, vectorization

I have data like this:

```
 1     0     1
 1     1     1
 0     1     1
 1     1     1
 1     1     1
 1     1     1
 1     1     0
 1     1     1
 1     1     1
 1     1     1
 1     1     1
 1     1     1
 1     1     1
 1     1     1
 0     0     1
 1     1     1
 1     1     1
 1     1     1
```

Each column represents a device, and each row represents a time period. Each data point indicates whether or not the device was active in that time period. I'm trying to calculate the length of each uptime, or the "spell", that each device was active. In other words, the length of each spell of continuous ones in each column. In this case, it would be `2 11 3` for the first column, and so on.

This is easy to do with one device (a single column of data):

```
rng(1)

%% Parameters
lambda = 0.05;      % Pr(failure)
N = 1;              % number of devices
T = 18;             % number of time periods in sample

%% Generate example data
device_status = [rand(T, N) >= lambda ; false(1, N)];

%% Calculate spell lengths, i.e. duration of uptime for each device
cumul_status = cumsum(device_status);

% The 'cumul_status > 0' condition excludes the case where the vector begins with one
% or more zeros
cumul_uptimes = cumul_status(device_status == 0 & cumul_status > 0);
uptimes = cumul_uptimes - [0 ; cumul_uptimes(1:end-1)];
```

so I could simply iterate over the columns and do this one column at a time and using `parfor` (for example) to run this in parallel. Is there a way to do this across all columns simultaneously, using vectorized matrix operations?

EDIT: I should add that this is complicated by the fact that each device may have a different number of spells of uptimes.

Comment: You can try to use something like: `reshape(max(cumsum(cumprod(hankel([zeros(1,size(A,2));A])'))),size(A,1)+1,size(A,2));` Where A is the matrix. Then you can find the local maxima, but sometime it is better and faster to use a loop.

Comment: If you don't have that many devices, then I think using this approach with a loop is perfectly fine.  Don't overcomplicate things.  Donald Knuth said it the best "*Premature optimization is the root of all evil*".  Unless you can clearly see a huge runtime difference between looping over each device individually than trying to do this for all devices in a vectorized manner, it's not worth the effort.

Comment: Also as a sidenote, you may not get the same amount of uptimes for each column.  Specifically in your example, the first column has three instances of uptime while the last two have two. This "uneveness" already hinders your ability for vectorization.

Comment: @rayryeng That's a good point. I was aware of that initially but I forgot to state it clearly in my question. I added an edit. Also, you're right that a loop is probably my best bet. I mainly asked this question for education's sake, since I always learn quite a bit when I ask questions on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way. Not sure it counts as vectorized, though.

Let your data matrix be denoted as `x`. Then

```
[ii, jj] = find([true(1,size(x,2)); ~x; true(1,size(x,2))]);
result = accumarray(jj, ii, [], @(x){nonzeros(diff(x)-1)});
```

produces a cell array, where each cell corresponds to a column. In your example,

```
result{1} =
     2
    11
     3
result{2} =
    13
     3
result{3} =
     6
    11
```

**How this works**

The idea is to find the row and column indices of zeros in `x` (that is, `true` values in `~x`), and then use the column indices as grouping variables (first argument to [`accumarray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html)).

Within each group we use the [anonymous function](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) `@(x){nonzeros(diff(x)-1)}` to compute the differences in row positions of zeros. We can apply [`diff`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) directly because the column indices from [`find`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) are already sorted, thanks to Matlab's [column major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) order. We subtract `1` because the zeros in `x` don't count as part of the uptime; remove uptime lengths equal to `0` (with [`nonzeros`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nonzeros.html)), and pack the resulting vector in a cell (`{...}`).

A row of `true` values is appended and prepended to `~x` to make sure we detect the initial and final uptime periods.